# Android Bottombar with two buttons having different backgrounds and a common background for two buttons

Tags: android

I have a linear layout in my main.xml which has a listview. Now I want to create a bottom bar below listview.

Bottombar has a background image and two buttons with their individual background images. I want to put these two buttons on common background image.

I have read that this can be achieved using FrameLayout. But since I am using LinearLayout as base layout in my main.xml, is there any way to this design using linearlayout ?

Comment: You might consider adding some screenshots that explain your proposed design better. `FrameLayout` would be useless for your situation, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of what you want to achieve simply using linearlayout and using weighting to get the bottom bar to display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#FF0000FF"
/>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="100dip" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#FF00FF00"
>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 1"
    />  
    <Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button 2"
    />      
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Linearlayout example view http://web11.twitpic.com/img/91422474-946af96885721237646940af1c9328a9.4bd47fa4-full.png](http://web11.twitpic.com/img/91422474-946af96885721237646940af1c9328a9.4bd47fa4-full.png)

And you can get the backgrounds just by changing the solid colors I've shown to something like:

```
    android:background="@drawable/background.png"
```